# Show Certain form based on if logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to show one form vs. the other depending on the if statement.  But when this runs, both forms show and also the if statement itself is showing as literal text instead:

```
if(model.CarId == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Car))
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CarModels", "Users", FormMethod.Post, new { @model = Model }))
    {
        <p>Car Model @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CarModel)</p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Find Model" /></p>
    }
}
else
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateCar", "Cars", FormMethod.Post, new { @model = Model }))
    {
        <p>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Name) Name</p>

        <p><input type="submit" value="Update" /></p>
    }                           
}
```

I know I need an @ next to if but tried that and then the view coplains about the rest of the syntax inside the @if when I do that.

**UPDATE**

Here's what finally worked:

```
@{
    if (Model.CarId == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Car))
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("CarModels", "Users", FormMethod.Post, new { model = Model }))
        {
            <p>Car Model @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CarModel)</p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Find Model" /></p>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateCar", "Cars", FormMethod.Post, new { model = Model }))
        {
            <p>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Name) Name</p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Update" /></p>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider changing your code like this:

```
@{
    if (Model.CarId == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Car))
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("CarModels", "Users", FormMethod.Post, new { @model = Model }))
        {
            <p>Car Model @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CarModel)</p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Find Model" /></p>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateCar", "Cars", FormMethod.Post, new { @model = Model }))
        {
            <p>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Name) Name</p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Update" /></p>
        }
    }
}
```

The "@{ .. }" block is used to insert arbitrary number of code lines.

Comment: When I use that, then the model type is not recognized anymore by the VS editor.  And then I also get an error "expected )" after the using statement's end bracket "}"

Comment: had to take out the @ for @model in the BeginForm

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a @ before the if and remove it before the using, as it is still considered as code instead of markup.